# Flask-webage background image doesnt work

Tags: python, css, flask, background-image

Below is a simple html code

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Webpage</title>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="sylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<style type=text/css>
    background-image: url("static/images/back.png");
</style>
<p>Does the Image Work? </p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Flask code:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="static", static_folder="static")

@app.route("/")
def main():

    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I get this error when I tried to inspect the page:
 **GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/images/back.png-404(NOT FOUND)**

I read through a couple of other forums, but couldn't find any solution to this problem. My images are in the following folder:

Flaskapp
        templates
        static
              images
                     back.png

When I open the index.html file, it works perfect, but when I try to run the python file to run the server, the background image isnt seen.

Not really sure how to proceed.

Comment: did you try putting an absolute path to the static folder?

Comment: Yes, did that too. It didn't work. I got an error stating not allowed to load local resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put the static folder next to the flask app

```
/FlaskApp
    -app.py
    static/
        images/
             -back.png
    templates/
         -index.html
         ....
```

you should not have to even tell flask about it... it will just know

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():

    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```